# Solve eigenvalue problem $(\frac{u'}{x})'+\frac{\lambda}{x}u=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, eigenfunctions

Consider the eigenvalue $(\frac{u'}{x})'+\frac{\lambda}{x}u=0$,$x\in (1,2)$.

And $u(1)=u(2)=0$.

I want to determine the sign of the eigenvalues first. But since it is not a standard eigenvalue problem in the form of $x''+\lambda x=0$. I can not seem to just check if it satisfies symmetric boundary condition. I tried to perform some transformations on $u$ to make the equation more regular but failed.

Any hints on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be useful. We have
$$(\frac{u'}{x})'+\frac{\lambda}{x}u=0,$$
let $xz = u$, hence we rewrite the equation as it follows
$$\frac{z'}{x} - \frac{z}{x^2} + z'' +\lambda z = 0,$$
multiplying by $x^2$ we obtain,
$$x^2z''+xz'+(\lambda x^2 - 1)z =0,$$
let $t = \sqrt{\lambda} x$
$$t^2z''(t) + tz'(t)+(t^2-1)z(t)=0,$$
it is a [Bessel's differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function).
So, 
$$z(t) = AJ_1(t) + BY_1(t),$$
and therefore
$$u(x) = AxJ_1(\sqrt{\lambda}x)+BxY_1(\sqrt{\lambda}x).$$

Answer (score 0):

If you let $u(x)=\sum a_nx^n$, you find $a_n\neq0$ for even $n$.  So let $v(x^2)=u(x)$ and find the DE that $v(y)$ satisfies.